# How Can I Check If Any IF Block Executed In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my SQL Server stored procedure, I have a number of IF blocks.

```
IF @CurrentStatus IN (1, 4) AND @RoleID IN ('ADMN', 'PMGR', 'SMGR', 'DMGR', 'DESI', 'DERO')
    BEGIN
            -- SELECT query...
    END

IF @CurrentStatus = 2 AND @RoleID IN('ADMN')
    BEGIN
            -- SELECT query...
    END
```

There are several more `IF` blocks like these. When none of the queries are executed because the conditions of the `IF` are not met, there will be no data returned. I have a query I want to return as the default if there is no other data being returned. How can I check if any data is being returned at the end of my stored procedure?

I tried checking if any queries had been executed with `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` but when one of the `IF` blocks executed, I would get 2 result sets.

Comment: Hi in your script if you only highlight what you want to run and execute the script then sql server will only run that block. If there is a problem with the code block then you will only get output for that block.

Comment: My stored procedure is being called from ADO.NET.

Comment: Try the SQL profiler tool in the tools menu of SQL server management studio. If you put a breakpoint on the ADO.Net code the profiler will run the SP for you and allow you to see where the issues are.

Here you go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: The stored procedure works just as I want it to, there are no issues with the code executing when ONE of the IF blocks gets executed. What I am asking is how can I check if one of the blocks got executed. I guess I could just set a flag in the blocks and check for the state of the flag at the end of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use If / Else If / Else, like this...

```
IF @CurrentStatus IN (1, 4) AND @RoleID IN ('ADMN', 'PMGR', 'SMGR', 'DMGR', 'DESI', 'DERO')
    BEGIN
            -- SELECT query...
    END

Else IF @CurrentStatus = 2 AND @RoleID IN('ADMN')
    BEGIN
            -- SELECT query...
    END

Else
    BEGIN
       -- Default query
    END
```